# One day added in gmdate

Tags: php

I'm trying to understand how `gmdate` works, i have the next simple code:

```
<?
$seconds = 86399;
echo gmdate("d \d\a\y\s H:i:s",$seconds);
?>
```

The result i was expecting is `0 days 23:59:59`, but i get `1 days 23:59:59` why is returning one day?

I know that i can do something like this to avoid the problem:

```
<?
define("SECONDS_BY_DAY",86400);

$seconds = 86399;
echo floor($seconds / SECONDS_BY_DAY) . " days ";
echo gmdate("H:i:s",$seconds);
?>
```

But i want to understand why `gmdate` is returning one day instead of 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `d` format specifier does not print the number of whole days passed since the start of the Unix epoch; it prints the day of month.

Your `$seconds` value corresponds to 23:59:59 on January 1, 1970 -- hence `d` is 1.

To get the total number of days since the epoch start, use

```
$date = new DateTime('@'.$seconds);
$epoch = new DateTime("@0");

$diff = $date->diff($epoch);
echo $diff->days;
```

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the clarification, i was misunderstanding the `d` param.